# Why is there a gravitational attraction between two objects at rest with respect to each other?

Tags: general-relativity

From my understanding of relativity, gravity is not a force, but a result of the curvature of spacetime. If Object1 moves past Object2, even though it's moving in a straight line, its direction may change due to the distortion caused by Object2's mass.

However, what about the situation where Object1 is not moving? How can there be an attraction between two objects that are at rest relative to each other? i.e. what makes them move towards each other?

Comment: For practical applications the newtonian format is adequate, considering that it is where the limit of general relativity and special relativity end ( low relative velocities, low gravitational wells). an interesting map : http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2011/04/110406-new-map-earth-gravity-geoid-goce-esa-nasa-science/ here. At the interfaces two mountains at rest exert a horizontal force on each other, as the colors show by extrapolation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two objects that are initially at rest with respect to each other have initially parallel [world lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_line).

However, the curvature of spacetime means that world lines that are initially parallel do not remain so.  This is called geodesic deviation.

[image]

([Image credit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Earth_geo.gif))

In the above image, the geodesic segments are parallel at the equator but, nonetheless, converge at the pole.

Imagine the time direction (*and remember, every object is relentlessly "moving" forward through the time direction even when "at rest" in space*) is along lines of longitude and the spatial direction is along lines of latitude.

If the surface were, instead, a plane, the two geodesics would remain parallel and the objects associated with those world lines would not move towards or away from each other.

Comment: the important thing to remember is that even though the objects are not initially moving in space, they are moving in space-time because the time coordinate is changing. Thus they are forced to move non-trivially along a geodesic, and this geodesic will be affected by the curvature induced by the other objects stress-energy.

Comment: Lovely diagram Alfred, what did you draw it with?

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance, I can't take credit for it as I found it at Wikipedia.  I've added an attribution.

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs, I added a bit to my answer at your suggestion.